# Open SOCKS Client with Java

Tags: java, socks, proxy-classes

Is it possible trough Java programming connect to a SOCKS server in the same way that Hummingbird software makes?

I would like to create my own and free version of a java SOCKS client in order to 'socksify' any application that I use in my OS.

How can I get started with it?
I know that there are some java libraries but I don't see examples.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible ...

Yes. Java has a SOCKS client built in. See java.net.Proxy.

> I would like to create my own ...

Given that it is already possible, that would be redundant. A waste of your time in other words.